# How to generate images?

Tags: manpage, groff

Generates an HTML page with a link to image without image file:

```
man -Hfirefox 3 exit
```

Generates an HTML page with link and file, but it is empty (zero size).
Also generates the code for the table, but it is empty:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man3/exit.3.gz | groff -mandoc -Thtml > exit.3.html
```

Generates an html page with table, but the characters are misinterpreted.
In addition, some attributes (bold or underlined) are lost to certain words:

```
man -P cat 3 exit | man2html > exit.3.html
```

What is considered as an image is in fact a table (man 3 exit):

```
   ┌──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────┐
   │Interface │ Attribute     │ Value               │
   ├──────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────┤
   │exit()    │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe race:exit │
   └──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

netpbm-10.69.02-1 package is installed.
How to generate the images (or table in text mode) with the second method?

**EDIT:**
It is also necessary to install the psutils package. In this case, the PNG is created.
The content of the table is then visible but with no bordure.
And there has undesirable characters.